# Using LINQ to select distinct values between two tables

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I have a DataSet that looks like the below information.

[image: DataSet]

What I am trying to do is populate an object with as much information as available.

So I want to get UnitNum 65002 from the top dataset and the rest from the Single column table.

My Code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsUnits.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        var unit = new Unit.Unit 
        {
            UnitNum = row["UnitNumber"].NullSafeToString(),
            CustCode = row["CustCode"].NullSafeToString(),
            Year = row["Year"].NullSafeToString(),
            Make = row["Make"].NullSafeToString(),
            Model = row["Model"].NullSafeToString()
        };

        UnitsInvolvedInBreakdown.Add(unit);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dsUnits.Tables[1].Rows)
    {
        if (UnitsInvolvedInBreakdown.Where(x => x.UnitNum == row["UnitNumber"].ToString()).Count() == 0)
        {
            var unit = new Unit.Unit
            {
                UnitNum = row["UnitNumber"].ToString()
            };

            UnitsInvolvedInBreakdown.Add(unit);
        }
    }
```

This seems really inefficient to me, I tried the below code and go no results,

```
 var q = dsUnits.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Except(dsUnits.Tables[1].AsEnumerable());
```

My question basically, is there a way to use linq to select UnitNumbers from table 0, only if they do not exist in table 1

Better explanation.

The unit number will be in table 1. It might be in table 0.

If it is in table 0, I want to get the information from there..i have more info.

If it is not in table 0, I want to get the info from table 1 because I have to take what I can get. But I don't want duplicates.

Comment: Is this with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood your requirement this is what you're looking for. It first takes all from table one and then all that are not in table one but in table two via a Linq Left-Outer-Join:

```
var unitsFrom1 = dsUnits.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new Unit.Unit
    {
        UnitNum = row["UnitNumber"].NullSafeToString(),
        CustCode = row["CustCode"].NullSafeToString(),
        Year = row["Year"].NullSafeToString(),
        Make = row["Make"].NullSafeToString(),
        Model = row["Model"].NullSafeToString()
    });

var unitsFrom2Notin1 = 
    from row in dsUnits.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
    join u1 in unitsFrom1
    on row.Field<string>("UnitNumber") equals u1.UnitNum into outer
    from outerJoin in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where outerJoin == null
    select new Unit.Unit
    {
        UnitNum = row["UnitNumber"].NullSafeToString()
    };
```

Now you can concat both:

```
IEnumerable<Unit.Unit> result = unitsFrom1.Concat(unitsFrom2Notin1);
```

---

Here's a different approach that is more maintainable and should work in any case. You can implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Unit>` which you can use for many (set based) LINQ methods like `Join`, `Intersect`, `Union`, `GroupBy`. You can also use it for a `HashSet<Unit.Unit>` which i'd prefer in this case. Here is a possible implementation of the `UnitComparer`:

```
public class UnitComparer : IEqualityComparer<Unit>
{
    public bool Equals(Unit x, Unit y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true; 
        if (x == null || y == null) return false; 

        return x.UnitNum == y.UnitNum;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Unit obj)
    {
        return obj == null || obj.UnitNum == null ? 0 : obj.UnitNum.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and here is the simple loop that you need, take all from first and all that are not in the first from the second. Note the [`HashSet<T>` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx) that i use:

```
var uniqueUnits = new HashSet<Unit.Unit>(new Unit.UnitComparer());
foreach (DataRow row in dsUnits.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Unit.Unit unit = new Unit.Unit
    {
        UnitNum = row["UnitNumber"].NullSafeToString(),
        CustCode = row["CustCode"].NullSafeToString(),
        Year = row["Year"].NullSafeToString(),
        Make = row["Make"].NullSafeToString(),
        Model = row["Model"].NullSafeToString()
    };
    uniqueUnits.Add(unit);
}
foreach (DataRow row in dsUnits.Tables[1].Rows)
{
    Unit.Unit unit = new Unit.Unit
    {
        UnitNum = row["UnitNumber"].NullSafeToString()
    };
    uniqueUnits.Add(unit);
}
```

[`HashSet<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `false` if it could not be added because it was already in the set.

Comment: i like it. I was thinking there would be a way to make use of the Intersect function. Thank you. I am going to run some unit tests to see which performs faster.

Comment: @CalvinSmith: i don't see how `Intersect` could help here. If you had overridden `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in `Unit.Unit` you could use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You could also use the overload of [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358407(v=vs.100).aspx) with a custom `IEqualityComparer<Unit.Unit>`.

Comment: Also, it produced duplicate units 65002 in the concat. I dont think just adding a straight distinct on the end of concat could fix it but ill try that next

Comment: @CalvinSmith: no, you cannot use `Distinct` since that would only compare references by default. And both are different references with the same `UnitNumber`. That's why i mentioned `Equals`+`GetHashCode`. But i wonder why you get duplicates. The second LINQ query above should only take rows/units from the second table which are not already extracted from the first. That's why i've used the "outer-join" (`from outerJoin in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where outerJoin == null`).

Comment: @CalvinSmith: i have shown another approach using a custom `IEqualityComparer<Unit>`.

Comment: a little more complex than needed for this specific problem, but as a general solution defiantly helpful. I am going to use the original query but I encounter alot of problems similar to this( terrible legacy database) and will defiantly use this later on. Thank you.

Comment: for the record I figured out the problem, unit num has spaces after it and needed to be trimmed -.-

Answer (score 0):

I find that datasets tend to throw me off when I am in a linq frame of mind. I find it easier to build entities via classes and then query the entities using linq. For lack of time I have copied an MSDN example. You could modify this to your needs.

```
var query =
    from contact in contacts
    from order in orders
    where contact.ContactID == order.Contact.ContactID
        && order.TotalDue < totalDue
    select new
    {
        ContactID = contact.ContactID,
        LastName = contact.LastName,
        FirstName = contact.FirstName,
        OrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
        Total = order.TotalDue
    };

foreach (var smallOrder in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contact ID: {0} Name: {1}, {2} Order ID: {3} Total Due: ${4} ",
        smallOrder.ContactID, smallOrder.LastName, smallOrder.FirstName,
        smallOrder.OrderID, smallOrder.Total);
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear how this helps to take all from table 1 and all missing from table2 which is the core issue. The sample is completely unrelated, isn't it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: I was trying to suggest, without being overbearing a shift from querying datasets directly. Yes the sample is unrelated, but gives a linq construct that queries entities. It did not deal with how his query should look. I am going to look into that